# having a problem with ul's and li's in IE6

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am having this problem where I have a set of ul's and li's on my html page. when the li wraps to the second line the bullet is shown on the second line, and not on the first line where it should be. Does anyone have any suggestions as to why?

http://www.screencast.com/users/bibbles10504/folders/Jing/media/32ec77cc-a158-46fa-bdd9-341864c6af2f

the line starting with "asdf" should have a bullet with it, the line where the bullet is now is just a continuation of the first line

Comment: does it work in Firefox?

Comment: yup, all browsers are fine except ie 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.gunlaug.no/tos/moa_26.html